# XQuery - Copy Constructor?

Tags: xquery

Given the following query

```
let $a := xs:dateTime("2012-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00")
let $b := xs:dateTime($a)
let $c := xs:dateTime($a cast as xs:string)
(: cannot - don't know how to - execute the function without assignment :)
let $d := adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($a, xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1H"))
return (<a>{$a}</a>,<b>{$b}</b>,<c>{$c}</c>)
```

the output is as follows

```
<a>2012-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</a>
<b>2012-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</b>
<c>2012-01-01T00:00:00Z</c>
```

Based on [XQuery's documentation on constructor functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-constructor-functions) (*the constructor function for a given type is used to **convert** instances of other atomic types into the given type*) this is the expected behaviour. Calling *xs:dateTime($a)* simply returns *$a* as there is no need to cast, but *xs:dateTime($a cast as xs:string)*  creates a new *xs:string* from *$a* first. However this requires an extra conversion.

Is there any other way to tackle this problem? Or conversions are *cheap* and I shouldn't care?

(If it makes any difference my XQuery processor is [BaseX](http://basex.org/) 7.2.)

---

It seems it *does* a make a difference that I'm using BaseX. I've really thought that this is the way the *xs:dateTime* constructor function and the *adjust-dateTime-to-timezone* function should be working, this is why I misinterpreted the XQuery documentation.

Given the input I've been given by [Dimitre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) and [Ranon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695343/ranon) it seems the *problem* described is gone.

By the why my use case is, or more like it *was*, that I wanted to make a date-time interval based query against my XML data set's date-time element. Because the input parameters and the source date-time values used different time-zones I had to make time-zone corrections with the above function, which modified its input parameter (the original source date-time in my case), however I wanted to preserve the original value. Given the function's name *adjust-dateTime* I thought that it's okay that it modifies its argument, so I automatically thought that I had to *copy* my original value using a constructor function to be able to keep the original date-time value.

Comment: Your reported output is not one that can be produced by a compliant XQuery processor. Also, you don't specify what the problem is. Nor you specify what exactly you want to produce from a given `xs:dateTime`. Finally, there are no "copy-constructors" in XPath/XQuery -- these aren't C++ - like languages.

Comment: I've updated my question and add a bit of an explanation on what I'm trying to do. (On a side note, I've never said that there is or was a copy constructor in the language, I simply asked if there is one, because given my case it really seemed that there was a need for it - because the *adjust* function seemed to modify its argument.)

Comment: Kohányi Róbert: Yes, imperative names for functions do bring a lot of confusion -- we have the example of the `string.Replace()` method in C#, which doesn't modify its argument (because the `string` object in C# is immutable), but many people fail to assign the result of `Replace()` to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The output that is reported is incorrect**.

**The correct output (produced running Saxon under oXygen) is**:

```
<a>2012-01-01T00:00:00Z</a>
<b>2012-01-01T00:00:00Z</b>
<c>2012-01-01T00:00:00Z</c>
```

The `adjust-dateTime-to-timezone()` function, as any other function cannot modify its arguments -- its effect is only contained in the variable `$d` -- which you don't use in the `return` clause.

Comment: -1 for complete and direct content duplicate of my answer (apart from switching Zorba with other tools).

Comment: @Ranon: you must be confused. My answer isn't a duplicate of yours though both essentially say the same thing. Firstly, I provide the result from running the XQuery code, which you don't. Secondly, I explain the provided output shouldn't be produced and is incorrect and point out that the `$d` variable isn't used at all in producing the output. Finally, you go to extremes to state that one XQuery processor is buggy, while another isn't -- which I don't do, because I simply don't believe there is enough evidence for such an extreme statements. How can you call this "direct content duplicate"?

Comment: @Ranon: On the same basis I could -1 your answer for making an unfounded assumption that BaseX is buggy -- but I leave this to other people ... :)

Comment: I wrote: Result incorrect, that variables in XQuery are immutable so a fcuntion cannot change its argument, why $d is neccessary here. You wrote: Result incorrect, that a function cannot change its arguments, why $d is neccessary here. BaseX actually (and obviously) had a bug which is already fixed. My statement that there is a bug is founded in the few lines following this statement.

Comment: Obviously I summerized your answer, and I guess you didn't read mine. This is no revenge, this is a vote, and the OP indead stated mine *would* be the better/more complete/whatever one, but he thought you would have been faster. Although I really do not care about whatever answer got this green flag, I didn't like your answer being an exact content-clone of mine. This is a community page, feel free to edit mine if you think the correct output should have been included and not only linked (syntax stuff), but do not post an exact copy. Think we got kind of OT and this doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Ranon -- I agree that this has become an OT. And of course, I wouldn't be posting my answer if I thought yours was the perfect answer to this question. The difference is that I didn't downvote your answer, but simply offered mine, hoping that it would be more understandable to the OP. Also, I simply didn't believe he got that output and wanted to point out that he must have done some kind of mistake, providing an impossible output. I don't approve of downvoting in such situation -- the principle should be to let the OP and readers choose what is best for them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you ran into some really weird bug.

Your line 5 shouldn't change `$a-c` at all as XQuery is a functional programming language with immutable variables (`adjust-dateTime-to-timezone` should not change your variables) and without side effects. Thats why you were forced to assign `$d`, otherwise your calculated results directly would have been thrown away.

I just submitted some bug request. [Zorba is doing your query right](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#ESml4L3s0F/nCvV5mJHPRS3etwQ=), you can use it for understanding the problem.

BaseX as you preferred XQuery processor will do within few days, too. I or some other BaseX team member will trigger you here as soon as it's fixed.

I guess your problem arised from missunderstanding and wrong behaviour of BaseX and should be solved. Feel free to ask again if anything stayed unclear with your query.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've accepted Dimitre's answer just because he was faster, although both of your explanation is right on spot (yours, on why I was forced to make an assignment was a nice little extra).

Comment: I pushed a bugfix commit yesterday in the evening, which should be included in todays [nightly build](http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/) (will be included in April 09 release). Feel free to fetch it though it is a development prerelease and not released for production.